# Render panel changed?

Tags: rendering, properties

Where did everything go?
No "Feature Set" dropdown
No "Device" dropdown [CPU/GPU]
No Motion Blur, Light Paths, etc

[image: Render panel v2.79]

Comment: Are you set to Blender Internal renderer instead of Cycles?

Comment: OMG. Yes. I'm such a noob idiot. Thanks Rich

Comment: It’s really easy to get lost in the interface - there are a lot of options. Glad you’re back on track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender supports different render engines and these can have quite different options. In this case you seem to have selected Blender Internal renderer while you actually intend to use Cycles. Simply change the drop-down at the top of the window to Cycles.